# When I press tab in IE6 , it goes to address bar instead of next control

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-6, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've used c# and ajaxcontroltoolkit to develop a web site and I have a problem with ie6.

1. refresh the page
2. click on a textbox in the page.
3. press Tab key
4. instead of ie set focus to the next textbox, it set focus to the Address Bar -*-
5. press Tab key again
6. instead of ie set focus back to the page, it just blur from Address Bar and focus nothing (I can't press arrow key to scroll the page.)

Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem in IE8 & IE9 using asp.net 4.0 and ajax tool kit. someone help! please!